# »Im Großen und Ganzen« vs. »im großen und ganzen«

Tags: spelling, capitalization, reformed-orthography, nominalization

Die neuen Rechtschreibregeln empfehlen, *im Großen und Ganzen* groß zu schreiben. Die alten Regeln (die bis 1996 auch die offiziellen waren) sahen vor, *im großen und ganzen* klein zu schreiben (wie auch viele ähnliche Wendungen, etwa *im allgemeinen, im besonderen, im wesentlichen).*

Welche Argumente werden bzw. wurden für die beiden Schreibungen von ihren jeweiligen Verfechtern ins Feld geführt?

Comment: *Mich interessiert die Meinung anderer (professioneller) Nutzer des Deutschen, welche Schreibung vorzuziehen ist* – Diese Seite ist nicht für Umfragen gedacht und geeignet, aber ich denke, dass es Dir darum eh nicht ging, sondern um die Argumente. Deshalb habe ich Deine Frage entsprechend geändert, um sie nicht schließen zu müssen. Bitte überprüfe, ob alles noch in Deinem Sinne ist.

Comment: Nun, ich wollte nicht eigentlich Referate darüber einholen, welche Argumente in bisherigen Diskussionen zwischen Miniaterialbeamten, Publizisten und Linguisten möglicherweise schon verwendet wurden (dann kommen wir wohl sehr schnell eben doch wieder zur Diskussion pro und contra "Rechtschreibreform"), sondern ich wollte erfahren, wie bewusste Nutzer des Deutschen (und nur solche werden sich hier tummeln) die Sache selbst empfinden. Aber wenn die Forenregeln die Umformulierung meiner Frage erfordern, dann: Danke.

Comment: Was sind Miniaterialbeamte? Meinten Sie: Ministerialbeamte?

Comment: Ja, Ministerialbeamte. Leider lassen sich Kommentare nach einiger Zeit nicht mehr korrigieren.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe »*im Großen und Ganzen*«, und auch die andern in der Frage genannten Beispiel auch schon in den 70er-, 80er- und 90er-Jahren groß (damals also falsch) geschrieben, weil im Wort »im« der Artikel »dem« steckt (*im = in dem*), was ich auch schon vor der Rechtschreibreform als unübersehbaren (damals aber irreführenden) Hinweis auf eine Substantivierung des nachfolgenden Adjektivs interpretiert habe. Ehrlich gesagt kann ich auch gar nicht nachvollziehen, aus welchem Grund man das damals kleinschreiben musste.

Ich weiß nicht, ob man auf meine obige Begründung das Etikett »kognitionswissenschaftlich« kleben kann. Aber die Großschreibung dieser Worte fügt sich konsistenter in die übrigen Regeln ein als die Kleinschreibung, und erscheint mir daher *natürlicher*.

Die Ästhetik spielt in der Rechtschreibung meiner Meinung nach ohnehin keine Rolle. Typographie hat mit Ästhetik zu tun, Rechtschreibung nicht.

Comment: Danke. - Zu Orthographie und Ästhetik: Es gibt vielleicht doch eine Berührung: im Schriftbild. Mein eigenes ästhetisches Empfinden neigt zu "im großen und ganzen", weil es - als zusammenhängender Begriff - schön glatt durchläuft. Der Ausdruck ist - für mich - abstrakt, fern von konkretem Großem und Ganzem, und ich denke, diese abstrakte Verwendung war der Grund, dass in Buchsetzerkreisen sich mit der Zeit diese Schreibung durchgesetzt hat. Aber danke für deine Schilderung!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich persönlich finde einen gewissen Anteil an großgeschriebenen Wörtern in deutschen Sätzen ästhetisch ansprechend, vermutlich aber aus reiner Gewohnheit. Jedenfalls finde ich den völligen Verzicht auf Großschreibung (also konsequente *kleinschreibung*, auch von *substantiven* und *satzanfängen*) als hässlich und schwer lesbar.

Comment: Absolut. Die Großschreibung hilft beim Erkennen der Wortgestalt auf einen Blick (vulgo Lesen). Das ist sehr angenehm. Ich vermisse das z.B. bei der kyrillischen Schrift extrem. (Hier wären wir beim kognitiven Aspekt der Sache.) Aber gerade das ist für mich auch wieder ein Grund, "im großen und ganzen" besser zu finden: die zwei großen Gs von "im Großen und Ganzen" lassen mich da eher stocken. Außerdm sind sie einfach sehr groß und dick und aufgeblasen, diese Gs, und das bei so einem abstrakten Begriff, der, find ich, lieber schlank und zurückhaltend bleiben sollte. Na gut. Geschmackssache.

Comment: Ich vermute, das liege an dieser Regel: Aus Substantiven entstandene Wörter anderer Wortarten werden kleingeschrieben, z.B. "ein paar" oder "ein bisschen". "Im Grossen und Ganzen" erfuellt im Grossen und Ganzen die Funktion eines adverbs. Da die Phrase nicht als Wort bezeichnet werden kann, wurde eine uebergreifende Regel wohl etwas gelockert. http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung